# PHP symfony routing issues

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony, routes

So I have a PHP website running in Symfony and I used XAMPP to setup apache and php. The website is nested under a few folders and it looks like this:
C:\xampp\htdocs\company\PHP_Site\website\web

So my website URL is: http://localhost/company/PHP_Site/website/web

I have a .htaccess file that its rewriting URLs so they look pretty and dont have the .php at the end.

```
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# Change below before deploying to production
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app_dev.php [QSA,L]
```

I have rewrite enabled in my httpd.conf file and everything.

The problem I'm having is that some of the URLs that get generated are looking like this: http://localhost/cart instead of http://localhost/company/PHP_Site/website/web/cart

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong in my routing configuration. Please help

Comment: The first step is to setup a virtual host which will map an url directly to your web directory.  That will enable you to use the Symfony htaccess out of the box and get rid of these sorts of errors.  Plenty of examples out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cerad says, you need to set your DocumentRoot directive to point at `C:\xampp\htdocs\company\PHP_Site\website\web` rather than `C:\xampp\htdocs\`. Also, instead of that .htaccess file above, you should instead put:

```
FallbackResource /app.php
```

in the main server configuration - which does the same thing.

`.htaccess` files are for people who don't have access to the server configuration file.